# Case Sensitivity Problem with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am trying to return an XML list from a MySQL database via PHP and am having issues with case sensitivity.  Here is the current code I'm using

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE FOO LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY FOO";
```

In my database I have first names listed as "Joe" so in order to return the XML I have to enter $term as "Joe".  I can't use "joe" or "JOE" but would like to.  I'm not sure if I can accomplish this directly through the PHP or whether I need to adjust the MySQL table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    foo
WHERE   foo COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%$term%'
ORDER BY
        foo
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a cheaty answer, but someone else went to the trouble of writing this out already.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html